# Setting up AWS Lambda With PHP - what is the entrypoint?

Tags: docker, lambda, dockerfile

I am working to set up AWS Lambda with a PHP application.  I have been able to set up the basic functionality as documented here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-php-lambda-functions-with-docker-container-images/

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM bref/php-80-fpm
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN php composer.phar require bref/bref
COPY . /var/task
CMD _HANDLER=index.php /opt/bootstrap
```

When I run a test on Lambda I get an error: `entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument`

I see in the linked post above there is a comment in the Dockerfile stating that this line sets the entry point:

```
#set the function handler entry point
CMD _HANDLER=index.php /opt/bootstrap
```

But I'm not sure what that line means.  The index.php file should be used as an entrypoint for my app but I don't know what `/opt/bootstrap` does.

Is someone able to explain what the entrypoint here is and how I would troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating my Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM bref/php-80-fpm
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN php composer.phar require bref/bref
COPY . /var/task
ENTRYPOINT php index.php $CONTROLLER $FUNCTION
```

And then set environment variables to serve as `$CONTROLLER` and `$FUNCTION`

Note that you can test this without setting environment variables for example if I want to run a function called `profile_update` within my `customers` controller then I could use `ENTRYPOINT php index.php customers profile_update`

As far as I understand it the ENTRYPOINT here is equivalent to a command line function for running a script on my app, or the equivalent of what I would use for a cron command.  In my app it follows the above format and this worked to resolve my error.

Answer (score 1):

LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT is Lambda’s predefined env variable for the code runtime.

The image will look for it in the LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT so you need to make sure that your code is copied to that folder when the image is built.